# Controling Menu Text Overflow in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to JQuery. I'm using a menu bar shown in the following link
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/UIElements/LargeDropDown/

The source code can be downlloaded from

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/14/ui-elements-search-box/

I have attatched the code and files to my project. 
The problem is that when i first open the page, it showing the contents in the right way as shown in the image below

[image: On Page Load]

and on mouse enter the list item expands and shows the sub details below correctly

[image: On Mouse Enter]

but when i move the mouse away from the item, the text overflows and comes down. if it is a single word then there is no problem but it there are two or more words this happens. You can see this in the image below

[image: Text Overflowed]

I'm also giving the javascript code

```
<!-- The JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Styles/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            /**
            * the menu
            */
            var $menu = $('#ldd_menu');
            /**
            * for each list element,
            * we show the submenu when hovering and
            * expand the span element (title) to 510px
            */
            $menu.children('li').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var $span = $this.children('span');
                $span.data('width', $span.width());
                $this.bind('mouseenter', function () {
                    $menu.find('.ldd_submenu').stop(true, true).hide();
                    $span.stop().animate({ 'width': '510px' }, 300, function () {
                        $this.find('.ldd_submenu').slideDown(300);
                    });
                }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
                    $this.find('.ldd_submenu').stop(true, true).hide();
                    $span.stop().animate({ 'width': $span.data('width') + 'px' }, 300);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Can you please help me out???

Comment: Have you tried `alert($span.width())` to verify there is a value there? I have a feeling it is related to that, possibly that the width is not defined when the object is read by the jQuery. Do you have a link to the actual broken code? It would help to be able to compare your implementation to the example.

Comment: you can download the code (css & JS) from the links i have given in the question

Comment: I'd suggest posting a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo of your code rather than asking/expecting us to download your code and recreate it. Make it easy for us, help *us* to help ***you***.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a min-width via CSS for your li ([W3School min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp)). The following code affects all your li coming after your ul with the id ldd_menu.

```
#ldd_menu li {
  min-width:200px
}
```

You could also use for only one specific li.

```
<li style="min-width:200px">
```

Or via jquery in your each-block ([jQuery CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/))

```
$span.css("min-width", "200px");
```